# Rich Text Editor in Oracle Apex 18.2

Tags: oracle-apex, rich-text-editor

I am using Rich text Editor with maximum characters as 2000, however it is CLOB type in the table. But I am still able to enter characters more than 2000. I should not allow users to enter characters more than 2000.

Any one please suggest on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Select the rich editor item and go to: -> Validation -> Maximum Length

Comment: By setting this property, the characters limit is not restricted for RTE.

Comment: I just ran a test and the Maximum Length setting worked fine. Could you please reproduce your issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Please find below.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=140355:1:703705552758283::::: 
user_name: DEMOTEST
password: apex1234